# How to Display an image in a picturebox from another folder?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have an image "back.jpg" in the location: projectfolder/image/back.jpg and I'm trying to load the image on a picturebox. I'm trying the following code but It didn't work.

```
this.pictureBox.ImageLocation = @"\image\back.jpg";
```

If I have the Image in H:\back.jpg . The following code is working

```
this.pictureBox.ImageLocation = @"H:\back.jpg";
```

What's wrong with this code?`this.pictureBox.ImageLocation = @"\image\back.jpg";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path should be: `@"..\..\image\av.jpg"`, because you're running your application from `"Folder\bin\debug"` folder, and the image is 2 folders higher.

Your path `@"\image\back.jpg"` means that your're referring the root folder, i.e. you're targeting at "H:\image\back.jpg".

The best pattern here would be:

1. Include the image file to your solution in VS (if you haven't done it yet)
2. Go to the included file properties and set "Copy if newer" to "Copy if newer"
3. Use this code: `this.pictureBox.ImageLocation = "back.jpg";`

Comment: When I am using @"H:\back.jpg"; I need not to include that image and @"..\..\image\back.jpg" also not working. Do I really need to include ?I also put that image on debug folder and used location as "back.jpg",didn't work.

Comment: 1. How do you start your application (from VS of some how else)?
2. What type of project is it?
3. How many projects do you have in your solution?

Comment: I have one project in my solution.In the project folder I have a image folder. I can display image using Resources. As I have huge number of images so I want to use another folder named image which is in the main project folder alongside with program.cs , bin-folder etc and I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: The problem was I was using that path at the designing time which I needed to use in the run-time. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Set the image file to be copied to the output directory always and refer to it only with the file name.

Comment: Putting "\" in the beginning just gets you to the root of the drive, for example c:\